# Rails vs. websockets: Triggering a controller method on model changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, rails-activerecord

I'm currently working on a rails app. The app takes temperature data via a daemon (running in the background). Every time a new temperature object is saved and the temperature exceeds a certain level, I want to display the new data to the user (asynchronous via websockets).

To handle the websocket communication, the websocket-rails gem is used (https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails).

The websocket communication itself works fine. But I don't know how to trigger the websocket controller method on a model change, without breaking the mvc principles.

**Is there a clean way to solve this problem?**

Additional information:

Currently the daemon adds a temperature object every 20 seconds. But this value depends on settings and the count of measurement points.

temperature model:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: measurements
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  value       :float
#  measured_at :datetime
#  created_at  :datetime
#  updated_at  :datetime
#

class Measurement < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

The daemon uses different external sources (I don't think details matter that much) and creates new objects:

```
newTemp = Measurement.new
# set values ...
newTemp.save
```

Comment: How is data collected from the daemon? How often? What does a temperature object look like?

Comment: The temperature is stored in a simple model (ActiveRecord). I added the detailed information to the original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to use this, as docs says:

Broadcast to the channel from anywhere inside your Rails application. An existing controller, a model, a background job, or a new WebsocketRails controller.

```
latest_post = Post.latest
WebsocketRails[:posts].trigger 'new', latest_post
```

check it out:
[Documentation](http://websocket-rails.github.io/)

Answer (score 1):

Daemon should post new temperature objects through a controller interface, just like a regular web request. Accessing objects directly (not via controller) breaks the MVC pattern.

My suggestion is to implement `trigger_value:float` and `triggered?:boolean` attributes in `Temperature`.

- (Controller, before save) Pass a trigger value along with temperature daemon data to a new `Temperature` object.
- (Model, during save) Calculate whether temperature value exceeds trigger value; set `triggered?` boolean accordingly.
- (Controller, after save) After create, read the `triggered?` boolean; publish message to client if necessary.

Comment: I dont think you understood the question. He's trying to trigger the websocket event from outside its controller. I'm with the same doubt. If you manage to make this work, let me know.